# Json com problema, nao continua a execução após o request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, json

Código do contorller

```
public JsonResult InsertComment(string description, int postID)
{
    try
    {
        Comment comment = new Comment
        {
            Content = description,
            DataCommented = DateTime.Now,
            PostID = postID,
            UserID = User.Identity.GetUserId()
        };
        db.Comments.Add(comment);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {


    }
    return Json(comment, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Código do Json

```
$(function () {
    if (CommentInput.value != "") {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/Comment/InsertComment',
            dataType: 'Json',
            cache: false,
            async: true,
            data: { postID: CommentInput.getAttribute('data-postid'),      description: CommentInput.value },
            success: function () {
                alert('oi');                     
            }
        });
        CommentInput.value = "";
    }
});
```

O *comment* é inserido normalmente, contudo não executa o `alert` no `sucess`, o que está errado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente dar um retorno em vez de `null`.

```
public JsonResult InsertComment(string description, int postID)
{
    try
    {
        Comment comment = new Comment
        {
            Content = description,
            DataCommented = DateTime.Now,
            PostID = postID,
            UserID = User.Identity.GetUserId()
        };
        db.Comments.Add(comment);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {


    }
    return Json(postID, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

***Porque:***

O JQuery espera um dado, um valor, para passar pelo `success`, como foi enviado `null` não foi enviado nada e com isso também não foi executado o `success`

Comment: funcionou, teria alguma explicaçao sobre isso para acrescentar? darei a resposta como certa em 8minutos.

Comment: Sim vou colocar! se ta retornando null então não houve sucesso